# How to get billing info for each account returned in getAllOwnedAccounts() in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am developing a billing application using Softlayer.

My userID and API Key is from my Brand's Master account, just below Brand, and I have created 3 accounts under my brand.  I can retrieve the list of accounts using getAllOwnedAccounts(). However, I need to retrieve additional information for each account, such as invoices (and associated invoice items) and storage (LUNs, NAS, etc.).

How can I retrieve this data using my Master Account?  API calls using client['Account'].getInvoices() don't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get that information from your accounts, using API, is using their API credentials in your request. Currently when you call the API

```
client['Account'].getInvoices()
```

you are getting empty result, becasue you are using the credentials of your Brand's Master account, you need to use the credentials of the accounts that you created.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, I've

Comment: I may have another, albeit tedious, solution, using masking:acct_mask = 'allOwnedAccounts.invoices,allOwnedAccounts.invoices.invoiceTopLevelItems,allOwnedAccounts.invoices.invoiceTopLevelItems.children,allOwnedAccounts.invoices.invoiceTopLevelItems.billingItem,allOwnedAccounts.networkStorage,allOwnedAccounts.invoices.items'

                accounts = self.client['Account'].getOwnedBrands(mask=acct_mask)
                logger.info("Brand Accounts - {}".format(accounts))

Comment: if that works for you great, but maybe you cannot get some data using objectMask. the best way to gel all data is using the credentials of your account, if you want only use the credentials of your brand account you could use inpersonation (but this only work using soap requests)